# Searching for lastLogon attribute of user in multiple domain servers

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

First of all, please forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminologies. Correct me wherever I'm using the wrong terminology.

The objective is to programmatically retrieve the `lastLogon` date of a given username.

We have what I believe is a forest; two AD servers like  - `adserver01.aa.mycompany.com` and `adserver02.aa.mycompany.com`

I connected to these servers from a third machine using Microsoft's ADExplorer to inspect the objects. There I see some users having lastLogon date available in `adserver01`, but not in `adserver02`. For example, the value for lastLogon is 0x0 in `adserver02` whereas it is a valid date in `adserver01` for some users.

The code I've developed so far as a Windows Forms application, works fine if only one AD Server is involved. How do I check both servers and return the non-zero value if available, in either for lastLogon date attribute?

```
        private static string GetLastActivityDate(string UserName)
    {
        string domainAndUserName = String.Format(@"LDAP://aa.mycompany.com/CN={0},OU=CLIENT_PROD,OU=clients.mycompany.com,DC=aa,DC=mycompany,DC=com", UserName);
        string OUAdminUserName = "abc";
        string OUAdminPassword = "xyz";
        AuthenticationTypes at = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        DateTime lastActivityDate;
        string returnvalue;
        long lastLogonDateAsLong;


        using (DirectoryEntry entryUser = new DirectoryEntry(domainAndUserName, OUAdminUserName, OUAdminPassword, at))
        using (DirectorySearcher mysearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entryUser))
            try
            {
                using (SearchResultCollection results = mysearcher.FindAll())
                {
                    if (results.Count >= 1)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = results[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
                        lastLogonDateAsLong = GetInt64(de, "lastLogon");
                        try
                        {
                            if (lastLogonDateAsLong != -1)
                            {
                                lastActivityDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogonDateAsLong);
                                returnvalue = lastActivityDate.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                returnvalue = "-Not available-";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException aore)
                        {
                            returnvalue = "Not available";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnvalue = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException dsce)
            {
                returnvalue = "- Not available -";
            }


        return returnvalue;
    }
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
 private static Int64 GetInt64(DirectoryEntry entry, string attr)
    {

        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(
            entry,
            String.Format("({0}=*)", attr),
            new string[] { attr },
            SearchScope.Base
            );

        SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

        if (sr != null)
        {
            if (sr.Properties.Contains(attr))
            {
                return (Int64)sr.Properties[attr][0];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Forgot to mention, the AD schema, structure etc, looks exactly alike in the two servers.

Comment: if it works fine for one ..then replace the hard coded LDAP Connection sting with variables that you either read from a .config file or that can be passed / parsed from a domain or url.. or basically have a List<T> and pass that List<T> object into your Method as a Param and within a for loop you can accomplish the same thing with the existing working code with a few minor hard coded value changes to Parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this post
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19181/Find-LastLogon-Across-All-Windows-Domain-Controlle

I had the same issue but but only for one domain,
I solved it by using the following code however i'm checking the lastLogin of all users

```
 public static Dictionary<string, DateTime> UsersLastLogOnDate()
   {
       var lastLogins = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
       DomainControllerCollection domains = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers;
       foreach (DomainController controller in domains)
       {
           try
           {
               using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", controller.Name)))
               {
                   using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry))
                   {
                       searcher.PageSize = 1000;
                       searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(!objectClass=computer))";
                       searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new[] { "distinguishedName", "lastLogon" });
                       foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searcher.FindAll())
                       {
                           if (searchResult.Properties.Contains("lastLogon"))
                           {
                               var lastLogOn = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)searchResult.Properties["lastLogon"][0]);
                               var username = Parser.ParseLdapAttrValue(searchResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString());
                               if (lastLogins.ContainsKey(username))
                               {
                                   if (DateTime.Compare(lastLogOn, lastLogins[username]) > 0)
                                   {
                                       lastLogins[username] = lastLogOn;
                                   }
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   lastLogins.Add(username, lastLogOn);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }

               }


           }
           catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comException)
           {
               // Domain controller is down or not responding
               Log.DebugFormat("Domain controller {0} is not responding.",controller.Name);
               Log.Error("Error in one of the domain controllers.", comException);
               continue;
           }
       }
       return lastLogins;
   }
```

On top of the code you can use the following to get all domains in a forest.

```
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();  
DomainCollection domains = currentForest.Domains;  
foreach(Domain domain in domains)  
{  
   // check code above  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a simpler approach?  There is actually another attribute lastLogonTimestamp, added with 2003 domain level I think, that tries to keep a single, consistent value across the domain for the last login.  Alas, it has a bizarre replication time pattern, and could be up to two weeks out of date.

Comment: You are correct, my  server admin told me that the 14 days out-of-sync is a known issue in Windows 2003.